# Why is lein ring uberwar not including main manifest attribute

Tags: clojure, web-deployment, leiningen

when I invoke java -jar my-application.war 
after using lein ring uberware 
I receive a response of no main manifest attribute, in my-app.war
here is my code:

the namespace below provides the :gen-class and -main function which are needed:

```
 (ns nutrif.core
  (:require [ring.middleware.params]
            [ring.middleware.resource :refer [wrap-resource]]
            [ring.adapter.jetty]
            [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:gen-class))



(defn handler [request]
  {:status 200
   :header {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
   :body (io/input-stream (io/resource "public/index.html"))})

(def app
  (wrap-resource handler "public"))


(defn -main
  [& [port]]
  (let [port (Integer. (or port
                           (System/getenv "PORT")
                           8080))]
    (ring.adapter.jetty/run-jetty #'app {:port  port
                                         :join? false})))
```

Here is the my project.clj which points to the namespace with the -main function. What am I missing ?

```
(defproject nutrif "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [ring "1.3.0"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.3.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.11"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[ring-serve "0.1.2"]
                     [javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]]
  :ring {:handler nutrif.core/app
         :resource-paths [resources public]}

  :main nutrif.core
  :aot [nutrif.core])
```

Comment: If you're going to run it as a standalone app you want to create an uberjar, not an uberwar via ring. uberwar is for deployment via an app server.

Comment: lein uberjar works so I'm assuming the process is to load the my-app.jar on my server and invoke java -jar my-app using lein trampoline, this may be an alternate method, however the my-app.war method allows me to run multiple apps on one server also it allows the dev to set server environment variables using tomcat or jetty, so I still need to solve the problem of my-app.war not packaging my main function.

Comment: I have seen nothing to indicate that an uberwar should also be runnable as a standalone jar. While I don't doubt it would be possible to create one, I wouldn't expect lein-ring to create one either. What's this about trampolining? With an uberjar or uberwar you shouldn't even have lein installed on your server, you should build an artifact, deploy it, and run it using your container of choice or java directly.

Comment: Regarding running multiple apps, it's better to use something like nginx configured with the right port for each route / subsite. Setting environment variables is trivial, much easier than getting a a servlet container properly configured.

Comment: lein trampoline will launch the my-app.jar file without the overhead of the lein jvm launch for managing lein tasks, however what I did in order to launch the my-app.jar file is invoked the the java -jar my-app.jar & running the task in the background which worked, however, this still does not solve the .war file issue.